# How to smooth the edges of my drawn face sets?

Tags: sculpting

I have just learned about the glory of face sets in sculpt mode. However, from the tutorials I've watched it says to hold Shift to smooth the edges out but that doesn't seem to be working for me and I continue to have pixelated edges. Is there a certain setting I have on or am missing to be able to smooth out my edges?

[image: FaceSetsSettings]

Comment: Hello, Shift should work but it will change your topology. Why do you show the Brush panel?

Comment: Because I was asking if there was a setting I may not have selected that isn't allowing me to smooth my edges.

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/